# Java - calling on constructor- Compiler error

Tags: java

Here is my `field.java` class. Ive got the `public Field(String name, int number)` defined here.

```
public class Field 
{
    String name;
    int number; 

public Field(String name, int number){
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getNumber() {
    return number;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Field{" + "name=" + name + ", number=" + number + '}';
}


}
```

Here is my `Player.java` class, Im getting an error on my `Field currentField = new Field();` - it says that my Field is not defined as a constructor in my `Field.java` class

```
public class Player 
{
    private String name;
    private int pos;
    Field currentField = new Field();




    public Player()
    {

    }
}
```

Anyone got a suggestion on why Im throwing errors?

Comment: Where does a parameter-less constructor exist in `Field`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have provided a parameterized constructor in your class

```
public Field(String name, int number){
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
}
```

**And hence no default (no-arg) constructor is provided when you define a parametrized constructor.**

So when you are trying to create an instance using `Field currentField = new Field();`, it cannot compile since there is no matching constructor.

**Solutions you can try:**

**1.
Add a no-arg constructor to your class :**

```
public Field()
{

}
```

Or

**2.
While creating an instance, pass values to constrcutor :**

```
Field currentField = new Field("abc", 123);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes because your class receiving two arguments name and number and you are trying to create instance of it without passing them.

Either you can pass them

```
 Field currentField = new Field("test", 1); // for ex :
```

or create a default no arg constructor to your Field class.

```
/** default no arg constructor **/

public Field(){

// TODO : when there is no param 

}
```

Comment: Can you explain it in layman terms please? Im having trouble understanding this explanation.

Comment: @LarsPetriChristensen Which part you didn't get ?

Comment: Ive worked with a collegue on it now and ive understood this explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Field currentField = new Field();
```

You are not passing any arguments to the constructor. You will either need to provide a name and number as parameters, or define a default constructor :

```
public Field(String name, int number){
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
}

Field currentField = new Field("fieldName", 1);
```

or

```
public Field(){
    this.name = "";
    this.number = 0;    
}

Field currentField = new Field();
```

Answer (score 0):

In every Java class there is a default constructor, if you add any other constructor it will override the default constructor. So to make your code work you have to add no argument constructor.

```
public Field(){
}
```